# Validate time format using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to validate a time input (like 10:30 am, 02:30 pm) using `preg_match()`

I use this,

```
 $pattern   =   "/([1-12]):([0-5])([0-9])( )(am|pm|AM|PM)/";
 if(preg_match($pattern,$time)){
   return true;
 }
```

But when i give an input like `10:30 pmxxxx` it will not validated.
I dont know whether the method is correct or not. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[...]` notation in regexes defines *character* class: something that's applied to the single character. It's alternation that should be used here instead:

```
0[1-9]|1[0-2]
```

... so the regex in whole would look like this:

```
/^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$/
```

Comment: Actually when i give 10:30 pm or 10:30 pmxxxxx, the function returns true....But i need the function to be true only for 10:30 pm

Comment: Then please be more specific in your question. You described what you want to be matched, but didn't say anything about what shouldn't match; the art of regex is finding balance between those - and other criterias, like readability and performance.

Comment: @raina77ow: what does `?:` mean?

Comment: It means that the pattern in parentheses is not caught as a subpattern. The parentheses are used only for the alternative.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski: Thanks for the explanation. So in this example (validation) `?:` has no meaning?

Comment: How to allow 5:30 PM instead of 05:30 PM? Is (?:[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM) ok?

Answer (score 7):

## DATETIME SOLUTION

You can validate all your date/time strings with [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

### Function

```
function isTimeValid($time) {
    return is_object(DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', $time));
}
```

### Example

```
foreach (['12:30 am', '13:30 am', '00:00 pm', '00:00 am', '12:30am', '15:50pm'] as $time) {
    echo "Time '$time' is " . (isTimeValid($time) ? "" : "not ") . "valid.\n";
}
```

### Example output

```
Time '12:30 am' is valid.
Time '13:30 am' is not valid.
Time '00:00 pm' is valid.
Time '00:00 am' is valid.
Time '12:30am' is valid.
Time '15:50pm' is not valid.
```

Comment: I had tried `function isDateValid($date)
  {
   return is_object(DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d",$date));
  }` for validate a date format, is it correct

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you can use this for any kind of date/time validation...

Comment: But it returns true when i give 2012/19/21...19 is not a valid month..:-(

Comment: I meant that you can use DateTime::createFromFormat for any date/time validators, but i didn't say the function will look like this...

Comment: You can use my validateDate function > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322824/php-preg-match-with-working-regex/12323025#12323025

Answer (score 1):

## REGEX SOLUTION

- `[1-12]` will not work, because this is not range definition, but `[` and `]` [means start and end character class definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php).
- use `/i` [pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) at end, so you don't need to write `PM, pm, pM, Pm, AM, am, aM, Am` combinations.
- PM and AM fetch can bi simpleffied with `[ap]m`.
- if you wish to validate whole string, then the string must be valid from the start to end with `^` and `$`.
- I added `\h` [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) (horizontal whitespace char) between time and pm|am, so time like `10:10am` can be valid to.

### Code:

```
$time = '10:30 am';
$pattern = '~^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])\h*([ap]m)$~i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $time, $m)) {
    print_r($m);
    return true;
}
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:30 am
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 30
    [3] => am
)
```

Comment: I had tried `function isDateValid($date)
  {
   return is_object(DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d",$date));
  }` for validate a date format, is it correct