# How can I format input fields to form time of day using PHP date() function?

Tags: php, date, time, formatting

I want the user to select a time of day which I then want to convert using the `date()` function so it can be inserted into a Mysql database `datetime` table field.

```
<select name="event-start-time-hours" class="event-time">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8" selected>8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>


<select name="event-start-time-mins" class="event-time">
    <option value="00" selected >00</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
</select>

<select name="event-start-timeofday" class="event-time">
    <option value="" selected >AM</option>
    <option value="">PM</option>
</select>
```

I tried:

```
    $time = $_POST['event-start-time-mins'] .$_POST['event-start-time-hours'];
    var_dump($dob = date("H:i:s", $time));
print_r($_POST['event-start-time-hours']); 
print_r($_POST['event-start-time-mins']);
```

Which returns:

> string(8) "01:03:22" 220

So how do I format this correctly? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)**.

```
$time = mktime($_POST['event-start-time-hours'], $_POST['event-start-time-mins'], 0);
var_dump($dob = date("H:i:s", $time));
```

See **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/1HecvD2r)**.

---

**Note :** If your are using `PM`, just add `12` to hours.

Comment: First parameter in `mktime` function is hour, and then minute.

Answer (score 1):

used mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year,is_dst); function for create date take refence of [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 1):

First fix your HTML, so your select has value :

```
<select name="event-start-timeofday" class="event-time">
    <option value="AM" selected>AM</option>
    <option value="PM">PM</option>
</select>
```

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

```php
$dt = new DateTime;
$offset = $_POST['event-start-timeofday'] == 'PM' ? 12 : 0;
$dt->setTime($_POST['event-start-time-hours'] + $offset, $_POST['event-start-time-mins']);
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```

If you need time validator, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12759655/67332) one.