# php check wether string is in formate of h:i A - h:i A

Tags: php, regex

I need check string, whether that string is in format of

```
date("h:i A") - date("h:i A")
```

(ex:6:00 AM- 3:00 PM)

How to check string is in correct format or not?

I need a function logic, like if it is not formatted correctly,return false otherwise true

Comment: Use regex to check this.

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12759306/2064981) and you're half way there ;)

Comment: `preg_match('/^([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5]\d [AP]M$/', $myString);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but I assume it's something like this:

```
$myString = '6:00 AM - 3:00 PM'
preg_match('/[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]\s(?:AM|PM)\s-\s[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]\s(?:AM|PM)/', $myString, $matches)
print $matches
?> 6:00 AM - 3:00 PM
```

Comment: it is failed for this condition 12:00 AM - 12:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear, but you'll need something like this

```
\d+:\d+\s[AP]M-\s\d+:\d+\s[AP]M
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it this way:

```
$str = '6:00 AM - 3:00 PM';

$parts = explode('-', $str, 2);

$format = '%l:%M %p';

var_dump( strptime($parts[0], $format) && strptime($parts[1], $format) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution as follows for my string

```
echo preg_match('/^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)( |)-( |)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$/', "12:00 AM - 12:00 AM");
```

you can find solution in [enter link description here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0pw5-k63f)