# PHP check user input date

Tags: php, validation, date

So, a user can input a birth date by typing it or using a date picker.
This could allow mistakes, so on the server side I'd like to check if it's a valid date.

I read a lot on strtotime() and saw a lot of examples, but not a 100% correct one.

This is what I have:

```
$geboortedatum = $_POST['geboortedatum'];
$geboortedatum = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($geboortedatum));
list($y, $m, $d) = explode("-", $geboortedatum);

// var_dump(checkdate($d,$m,$y));
if(checkdate($d, $m, $y)) {
    echo "OK Date";
}
else {
    echo "BAD Date";
    exit();
}
```

This works most of the time.
Is there any solid method to check if the input is a real and correct date?

// EDIT

That was not a good example!
It also doesn't work when the user inputs 31-31-1980.
This is also valid, although it shouldn't be!

Comment: strtotime is good, but it's not psychic. do NOT depend on it to validate abitrary input formats. It **WILL** screw up sooner or later.

Comment: Ok, sure, but how can I check the correct input then?
There must be a thing I can do to check if it's correct...

Comment: well, what's 01-02-03? Feb 1st, 2003? Jan 3rd, 2002? enforce a date format, and if what the user enters doesn't confirm, slap an error message in their face.

Comment: The date format is dd-mm-yyyy.
Just as listed in the 2nd line of the code!

When you input 31-02-1980 (dd-mm-yyyy) it is being accepted! Just want to figure out how to check if this is valid or not...

Comment: similar  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format/31133321     or  from manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a combination of `strtotime()` and `checkdate()` to see if the date is valid:

```
function isRealDate($date) { 
    if (false === strtotime($date)) { 
        return false;
    } 
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date); 
    return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}
```

**usage**

```
if (isRealDate($geboortedatum)) {
    // date is ok
}
else {
    // date is not ok
}
```

Comment: Can't get this code to work.
How can I call this function?

Something like this:
isRealDate($geboortedatum);

It never returns anything :(

Comment: This works pretty good...
Although a year like 1900 doesn't seem to be working.
But a year like 2 does, guess because of strtotime limitations.

So I'll make this the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With DateTime you can make the shortest date&time validator for all formats.

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28 12:12:12')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-30 12:12:12')); # false
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28', 'Y-m-d')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('28/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('30/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # false
var_dump(validateDate('14:50', 'H:i')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14:77', 'H:i')); # false
var_dump(validateDate(14, 'H')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14', 'H')); # true

var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28T12:12:12+02:00', 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP')); # true
# or
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28T12:12:12+02:00', DateTime::ATOM)); # true

var_dump(validateDate('Tue, 28 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', 'D, d M Y H:i:s O')); # true
# or
var_dump(validateDate('Tue, 28 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', DateTime::RSS)); # true
var_dump(validateDate('Tue, 27 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', DateTime::RSS)); # falsede here
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
function isValidDateTime($dateTime)
{    
    if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-])$/", $dateTime, $matches)) 
    {     
        if (checkdate($matches[2],$matches[3], $matches[1])) {             
            return true;        
        }    
    }     
    return false; 
}
```

Try the above code.

Comment: Not working...

Try for yourself inputting 31/31/2010.
It will still say valid date, although it isn't :(

Comment: I want to try this, but how can I call the function?
Something like: isValidDateTime($geboortedatum);???

Comment: Not working...

function isValidDateTime($dateTime)  {
 echo "function called";
 if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $dateTime, $matches)) {
  if (checkdate($matches[2],$matches[3], $matches[1])) {
   return true;
   echo "x";
  }
  else {
   echo "y";
  }
 }
 return false;
 echo "z";
}

isValidDateTime("1990-01-01");

It only returns "function called", nothing else :(

Comment: What parameters are you passing? Hav you ever worked with functions before?

Comment: Yes, I got to have a function working before.
This is what I passed: isValidDateTime("1990-01-01");

Comment: My function intakes date and time y-m-d h:i:s