# Correctly determine if date string is a valid date in that format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm receiving a date string from an API, and it is formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I am currently using a regex to validate the string format, which works ok, but I can see some cases where it could be a correct format according to the string but actually an invalid date. i.e. `2013-13-01`, for example.

Is there a better way in PHP to take a string such as `2013-13-01` and tell if it is a valid date or not for the format `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php date validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030810/php-date-validation)

Answer (score 589, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for this purpose:

```php
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    // The Y ( 4 digits year ) returns TRUE for any integer with any number of digits so changing the comparison from == to === fixes the issue.
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

<sup>[*Function taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332). Also on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205). Originally written by [Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332).*]</sup>

---

Test cases:

```
var_dump(validateDate('2013-13-01'));  // false
var_dump(validateDate('20132-13-01')); // false
var_dump(validateDate('2013-11-32'));  // false
var_dump(validateDate('2012-2-25'));   // false
var_dump(validateDate('2013-12-01'));  // true
var_dump(validateDate('1970-12-01'));  // true
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-29'));  // true
var_dump(validateDate('2012', 'Y'));   // true
var_dump(validateDate('12012', 'Y'));  // false
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/53309)

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.2.x, you should use `strtotime` to get the unix timestamp then `date('Y-m-d', $t)` to get the string date. Then you compare them just like this answer.

Comment: @pedromanoel: for standard datetime input you can use `strtotime`, but for non-standard formats that `strtotime` doesn't recognizes, you will need some other solution. And for php version 5.2 support stopped on January 2011, for 5.3 support stopped on August 2014.

Comment: consider this date `var_dump( validateDate('2012-2-9'));`

Comment: The function works correctly. It returned false because thr format you specified was incorrect. If you want to use day and month without leading zeroes, then the format should be `'Y-n-j'`,  @reignsly.

Comment: I don't see the point of ` $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date` part since $d would already be false if it wasn't the correct format?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea: no, it will not work without that part. Because `$d` will not be false in you give it date, which has overflown parts, like 13th month (2013-13-01). But it really depends what you want. If you need for example `validateDate('2015-55-66')` to be valid, then yes, you only need to check if `$d` is object or not.

Comment: why this is false var_dump( validateDate('2013-13-01')  ); this also a valid Y-d-m format date

Comment: @arsh: Yes, it's a valid `Y-d-m` format date. But in the function, I've given `Y-m-d`.

Comment: Sorry,  I just wandering for a function to determine any string is it date or not

Comment: this will return false on a date like this `'2016-12-11 10:15:00'`

Comment: @albanx: You can supply the date format as well. I have hardcoded it in the function, but you can change that however you want. `Y-m-d H:i:s`, for example.

Comment: You, also should check about DateTime::getLastErrors()

Comment: should be return $dt && (strtolower($dt->format($format))  == strtolower($string)); to make it work with  'january 2017' like formats

Comment: You should prepend '!' to the date format string to reset any non-defined date-time properties to 00 (unix epoch time). Otherwise with a pattern like 'Y-m' createFromFormat() will use the current time, which can lead to issues when converting timezones.

Comment: @Glavić Do you think the strict comparison is required here?

Comment: @AmalMurali: I have not used strict comparison in my answers; I even used string and int in my examples as valid (output true). It is all based on user requirements, but I think most users will not need strict comparisons.

Comment: Nonsense, why 12012 would be a bad year? WTH? Do they expect Earth or callendars are not gonna exist in the year of 12012?

Comment: does not work for  var_dump(validateDate('0018-08-23'));

Comment: `var_dump(validateDate('9:00'));` //  false

Answer (score 99):

Determine if any string is a date

```
function checkIsAValidDate($myDateString){
    return (bool)strtotime($myDateString);
}
```

Comment: This validates a whole range of valid date formats not just `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @MichelAyres this is because php sees `2015-02-30` as a valid date because when the day given is greater than the number of days in the given month (or negative) php rolls over to the next month.  Since the date is guaranteed to be of the format `yyyy-mm-dd` this can be fixed by changing the return to `return (bool)strtotime($myDateString) && date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myDateString)) == $myDateString;`.

Comment: Why does `(bool)strtotime('s')` come out as true?

Comment: this also returns 1
checkIsAValidDate("F");

Comment: we can use `$myDateString = str_replace("/", '-', $myDateString);` before return if the date string contains slashes (/) like :- dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @vaibhav,@Dainis
echo "$str == " . date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', $timestamp);

Comment: Important to note that this won't work with a British (d/m/Y) format as it will assume it's converting the American (m/d/Y). It will seem to work only if the day is lower than 12.

Comment: This is not correct! Will validate if you give it any integer or decimal! Use this only if you are sure that a string is being fed into the function.

Comment: this is incorrect (bool)strtotime("foo") returns true

Comment: This accepted answer is an error - why is the error answer accepted - and this not the answer? how do we fix this? We are sending people off with the wrong answer and to potential doom :/ and ... go figure - the person who posted this is aware it is an error and allows himself to collect points for an incorrect answer... figures.

Answer (score 50):

Use in simple way with php prebuilt function:

```
function checkmydate($date) {
  $tempDate = explode('-', $date);
  // checkdate(month, day, year)
  return checkdate($tempDate[1], $tempDate[2], $tempDate[0]);
}
```

**Test**

```
   checkmydate('2015-12-01'); //true
   checkmydate('2015-14-04'); //false
```

Comment: Again, when using a test, inside an `if` to return simply `true` or `false`, return the test itself.

Comment: This assumes there are at least 3 elements in the $tempDate array.

Comment: @person27: `return sizeof($tmpDate) == 3 && checkdate($tmpDate[1]...`

Comment: @vineet - this fails.  If the year is `2`, `20`, `202`, `2020` or even if the year is `20201` - it returns true every time.

Comment: d.m.Y is standart for almost every european country - and there are cases where it's something like Y/m/d [ although i don't understand how you could print day after month lol ] - you don't want to explode every possible input string.

Comment: This throws notices if `checkmydate('thisIsWrong!')`

Answer (score 19):

**Determine if string is a date, even if string is a non-standard format**

(strtotime doesn't accept any custom format)

```
<?php
function validateDateTime($dateStr, $format)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateStr);
    return $date && ($date->format($format) === $dateStr);
}

// These return true
validateDateTime('2001-03-10 17:16:18', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
validateDateTime('2001-03-10', 'Y-m-d');
validateDateTime('2001', 'Y');
validateDateTime('Mon', 'D');
validateDateTime('March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm', 'F j, Y, g:i a');
validateDateTime('March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm', 'F j, Y, g:i a');
validateDateTime('03.10.01', 'm.d.y');
validateDateTime('10, 3, 2001', 'j, n, Y');
validateDateTime('20010310', 'Ymd');
validateDateTime('05-16-18, 10-03-01', 'h-i-s, j-m-y');
validateDateTime('Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM', 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
validateDateTime('Wed, 25 Sep 2013 15:28:57', 'D, d M Y H:i:s');
validateDateTime('17:03:18 is the time', 'H:m:s \i\s \t\h\e \t\i\m\e');
validateDateTime('17:16:18', 'H:i:s');

// These return false
validateDateTime('2001-03-10 17:16:18', 'Y-m-D H:i:s');
validateDateTime('2001', 'm');
validateDateTime('Mon', 'D-m-y');
validateDateTime('Mon', 'D-m-y');
validateDateTime('2001-13-04', 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: When using a test, inside an `if` to return simply `true` or `false`, return the test itself.

Comment: But 2018-3-24 is returning false,the method receive 2018-3-24, when the format is apply return 2018-03-24; how I can return true in two ways?

Answer (score 17):

This option is not only simple but also accepts almost any format, although with non-standard formats it can be buggy.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
return $timestamp ? $date : null;
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer! Much, much simpler.

Comment: Important to note that this won't work with a British (d/m/Y) format as it will assume it's converting the American (m/d/Y). It will seem to work only if the day is lower than 12!

Comment: @galki - i tested this and it fails certain values.  If $date = '202-03-31' it returns true.  But thats not a valid date.  I found that if you alter the year to a non-valid year it always returns true.

Comment: @rolinger strange... maybe it’s seeing 202AD? What year’s timestamp does ‘strtotime’ give?

Comment: @galki - not certain, but `202` returns a negative number - which still passes the test.

Comment: @rolinger I can see a case where someone born in say 1950 would want their birthday to pass as a valid date, and that value would also probably be negative

Comment: the cleanest and simplest answer is by user4600953 below:  
'function isValidDate($date) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) === $date;
}'

Comment: @rolinger it's slower and more code for the same result.  '202-03-31' was a real date in the 3rd century, I don't understand why you claim it's not a valid date.

Comment: why is the error answer accepted - and this not the answer? how do we fix this? We are sending people off with the wrong answer and to potential doom :/

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to check if given date is valid probably converting it to unixtime using `strtotime`, formatting it to the given date's format, then comparing it:

```
function isValidDate($date) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) === $date;
}
```

Of course you can use regular expression to check for validness, but it will be limited to given format, every time you will have to edit it to satisfy another formats, and also it will be more than required. Built-in functions is the best way (in most cases) to achieve jobs.

Comment: I feel that this answer is pretty low quality, especially considering there are _already_ strtotime answers.

Comment: This is the shortest answer and it works. It is a bit harsh to say that it is low quality.

Comment: @user4600953 - this is the easiest one that works.  Lots of others are saying to use `checkdate()` - but I am finding checkdate fails if the year is ANY value: `2, 20, 202, 2020, 20201` - all return true.  I am going with your solution!

Answer (score 12):

You can also Parse the date for month date and year and then you can use the PHP function `checkdate()` which you can read about here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

You can also try this one:

```
$date="2013-13-01";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date))
    {
        echo 'Date is valid';
    }else{
        echo 'Date is invalid';
    }
```

Comment: in case of february (as commented by elitechief21)
function isValidDate($date) {
    return preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date) && date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) == $date;
}

Comment: This solution is very poor, as it doesn't check the date validity in any sense. Any month can have 31 days, including February. Any year can have 29 of February. To validate dates using RegExp would demand something much more complex, with back-references and negative look aheads.

Answer (score 12):

I'm afraid that most voted solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19271434/3283279) is not working properly. The fourth test case (var_dump(validateDate('2012-2-25')); // false) is wrong. The date is correct, because it corresponds to the format - the *m* allows a month **with or without** leading zero (see: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Therefore a date *2012-2-25* is in format *Y-m-d* and the test case must be true not false.

I believe that better solution is to test possible error as follows:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    $errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();

    return $errors['warning_count'] === 0 && $errors['error_count'] === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I have this thing that, even with PHP, I like to find **functional** solutions. So, for example, the answer given by @migli is really a good one, highly flexible and elegant.

But it has a problem: what if you need to validate a lot of DateTime strings with the same format? You would have to repeat the format all over the place, what goes against the **DRY** principle. We could put the format in a constant, but still, we would have to pass the constant as an argument to every function call.

But fear no more! We can use **currying** to our rescue! PHP doesn't make this task pleasant, but it's still possible to implement currying with PHP:

```
<?php
function validateDateTime($format)
{
    return function($dateStr) use ($format) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateStr);
        return $date && $date->format($format) === $dateStr;
    };
}
```

So, what we just did? Basically we wrapped the function body in an anonymous and returned such function instead. We can call the validation function like this:

```
validateDateTime('Y-m-d H:i:s')('2017-02-06 17:07:11'); // true
```

Yeah, not a big difference... but the real power comes from the **partially applied function**, made possible by currying:

```
// Get a partially applied function
$validate = validateDateTime('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Now you can use it everywhere, without repeating the format!
$validate('2017-02-06 17:09:31'); // true
$validate('1999-03-31 07:07:07'); // true
$validate('13-2-4 3:2:45'); // false
```

**Functional programming FTW!**

Comment: The best answer by a landslide IMHO(solves the specific problem of the OP with greater flexibility and pretty much the same amount of code as the rest of the answers)

Comment: IMHO this is really ugly programming, just put your values in an array and loop through them to validate, but please don't do this!

Comment: I'm curious @Tim, could you give us an example of your array/loop validation?

Answer (score 8):

Accordling with cl-sah's answer, but this sound better, shorter...

```
function checkmydate($date) {
  $tempDate = explode('-', $date);
  return checkdate($tempDate[1], $tempDate[2], $tempDate[0]);
}
```

Test

```
checkmydate('2015-12-01');//true
checkmydate('2015-14-04');//false
```

Comment: You'll need to test if `count($tempDate) === 3` though

Comment: @VDarricau no you don't, checkdate will bomb if they are missing, you could write isset() for every single one but i'd simply suppress the warnings

Answer (score 6):

Validate with **checkdate** function:

```
$date = '2019-02-30';

$date_parts = explode( '-', $date );

if(checkdate( $date_parts[1], $date_parts[2], $date_parts[0] )){
    //date is valid
}else{
    //date is invalid
}
```

Comment: Documentation for checkdate: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_checkdate.asp

Answer (score 4):

How about this one?

We simply use a try-catch block.

```
$dateTime = 'an invalid datetime';

try {
    $dateTimeObject = new DateTime($dateTime);
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo 'Do something with an invalid DateTime';
}
```

This approach is not limited to only one date/time format, and you don't need to define any function.

Comment: this will not work for datetime value 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: @NaseeruddinVN `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` is a valid datetime value. It's just the first the value. However, the date property of the datetime object will be `'-0001-11-30 00:00:00'`.

Answer (score 1):

Tested Regex solution:

```
    function isValidDate($date)
    {
            if (preg_match("/^(((((1[26]|2[048])00)|[12]\d([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48]))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|[12]\d))))|((([12]\d([02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789]))|((1[1345789]|2[1235679])00))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))))$/", $date)) {
                    return $date;
            }
            return null;
    }
```

This will return null if the date is invalid or is not yyyy-mm-dd format, otherwise it will return the date.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*********************************************************************************
Returns TRUE if the input parameter is a valid date string in "YYYY-MM-DD" format (aka "MySQL date format")
The date separator can be only the '-' character.
*********************************************************************************/
function isMysqlDate($yyyymmdd)
{
    return checkdate(substr($yyyymmdd, 5, 2), substr($yyyymmdd, 8), substr($yyyymmdd, 0, 4)) 
        && (substr($yyyymmdd, 4, 1) === '-') 
        && (substr($yyyymmdd, 7, 1) === '-');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the accepted answer, you can further check for a valid date or DateTime by checking if the formatted date is an `instanceof` `DateTime`.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $value);
$is_datetime = ($date instanceof DateTime);
$is_valid_datetime_format = $is_datetime
  ? ($date->format('Ymd') === $value)
  : false;

if (!$is_datetime || !$is_valid_datetime_format) {
  // Not a valid date.
  return false;
}
```

This will catch any values that are not a `DateTime` such as random strings or an invalid date such as `20202020`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**** date check is a recursive function. it's need 3 argument 
    MONTH,DAY,YEAR. ******/

    $always_valid_date = $this->date_check($month,$day,$year);

    private function date_check($month,$day,$year){

        /** checkdate() is a php function that check a date is valid 
        or not. if valid date it's return true else false.   **/

        $status = checkdate($month,$day,$year);

        if($status == true){

            $always_valid_date = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;

            return $always_valid_date;

        }else{
            $day = ($day - 1);

            /**recursive call**/

            return $this->date_check($month,$day,$year);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Code without any explanation isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try and let me know it works for me

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dataRowValue);
if (!empty($date)) {
//Your logic
}else{
//Error
}
```

if you pass any alpha or alphanumberic values it will give you the empty value in return

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution

```
function verify_date($date){
  /* correct format = "2012-09-15 11:23:32" or "2012-09-15"*/
  if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])( (0[0-9]|[1-2][0-4]):(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]):(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]))?$/",$date)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    die("Wrong date format: it should be '2012-09-15 11:23:32' or '2012-09-15', date received is: ".$date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$myday = '2022-1-30'; 
if (($timestamp = strtotime($myday)) === false) {
    echo 'The string ('.$myday.') is not date';
} else {
    echo 'The string ('.$myday.') is date = ' . date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', $timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use `date_parse`

> The array includes **warning_count and warnings** fields.
> *(snip)*
> The array also contains **error_count and errors** fields.
> [PHP: date_parse - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)

```php
function isValidDate($input) {
    $a = date_parse($input);
    return $a["warning_count"] == 0 && $a["error_count"] == 0;
}
```

For example:

```php
var_dump(isValidDate("2023-11-30"));  // true
var_dump(isValidDate("2023-11-31"));  // false (warnings: "The parsed date was invalid")
var_dump(isValidDate("2023-13-01"));  // false (errors: "Unexpected character")
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
$date = "2017-10-01";


function date_checker($input,$devider){
  $output = false;

  $input = explode($devider, $input);
  $year = $input[0];
  $month = $input[1];
  $day = $input[2];

  if (is_numeric($year) && is_numeric($month) && is_numeric($day)) {
    if (strlen($year) == 4 && strlen($month) == 2 && strlen($day) == 2) {
      $output = true;
    }
  }
  return $output;
}

if (date_checker($date, '-')) {
  echo "The function is working";
}else {
  echo "The function isNOT working";
}
```