# preg_match error Unknown modifier '('

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What's wrong with this?

```
public static function validaDataHoraBR($data_hora){
  $pattern = "/^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1,2][0-9]|3[0,1])/([1-9]|1[0,1,2])/\d{4} ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}$/";
  return (preg_match($pattern, $data_hora)) ? array(true) : array(false,' não é uma data e hora no formato BR!<br>'); 
}
```

This pattern validate this - 20/08/2011 21:00:00

Error: Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('

Comment: Why are you using a Regex to validate a date? [Use `DateTime` class instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19271434/1438393).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape `/` in the regular expression.

```
"/^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1,2][0-9]|3[0,1])\/([1-9]|1[0,1,2])\/\d{4} ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}$/"
#                                   ^                 ^
```

Otherwise, `/` is recognised as end of the regular expression.

Or use different delimiters:

```
"#^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1,2][0-9]|3[0,1])/([1-9]|1[0,1,2])/\d{4} ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}$#"
```

Comment: `+1`. Alternatively, you could use different delimiters. :)

Comment: I added that delimiter "#" to a preg_match I had like this. It worked perfect!