# Regular Expression to check d/m/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to check the date field is in format 'd/m/yyyy/ and /dd/mm/yyyy.. Can anyone provide me idea to do so...

Comment: Don't use a regex. Use DateTime class instead. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19271434/1438393).

Comment: Can get quite elaborate for days in a month... 28, 30, or 31 days, do we take leap years into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from wether or not you should or should not use regex, this is the way:

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}
```

- `\d` means digits ( `[0-9]` )
- `{1,2}` means 'the part before me should have at least **1** length, and maximum **2**
- `{4}` means exactly 4 characters long

**Edit:** This will match 1/2/2014 (both single), 11/12/2014 (both double) and 1/12/2014 (a single and a double).

Comment: I am getting this error, preg_match(): "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Comment: @Manadh: It seems you're using the regex as-is. You need to wrap it within valid delimiters: `/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}/`.

Comment: Which you could've found yourself with that exact query in google :)

Comment: I tried it in google but i am getting this error :preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: Use a delimiter to go around the regular expression above.  For example, I am using the tilde `~` as a delimiter here.  `if (preg_match('~\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}~', $date)) { print "DATE MATCHES"; }`

Comment: I presonally prefer the slash `/`, because in other programming languages that is common. That would require to escape the slashes in the regex to make them as content, not the end delimiter (so every `/` becomes `\/`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$yourdate="1/12/2002";
if (preg_match("/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/", $yourdate)) {
echo "Valid Date";
} else {
echo "Invalid Date";
}
```