# How to check in PHP if a DD/MM/YYYY exists in calendar?

Tags: php, date

I have a date format of DD/MM/YYYY and I want to check in a form submission whether the submitted date is present in the calendar or not.

Code:

```
$last_date = $_POST['last_date'];

$date = str_replace("/", "-", $last_date);
$d = explode("-"  , $date);

if( !checkdate($d[1], $d[0], $d[2]) )
    error[] = 'Warning! This date does not have any existence.';
```

Comment: What calendar are you talking about? There's nothing here that represents a calendar.

Comment: @JohnConde You are not getting it correct. I am talking about whether the date exists in the Real Life Calendar. The calendar which we follow. The Gregorian Calendar.

Comment: The Chinese don't follow that calendar, and they're about a 5th of the world's population.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format/19271434#19271434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate a Gregorian date you should use PHP's [`checkdate() function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

```
$date_to_check = checkdate('2', '29', 1969) ? 'good' : 'bad';
echo $date_to_check; // 'bad'
```

Comment: Thanks alot @JayBlanchard. Its always good to see that there are people interested in helping rather than criticizing. Your code worked.