# How to differentiate date formats as dd/mm/yy or dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: php, regex, validation, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to access the format of a given date value. I need to check whether the format is in `dd/mm/yy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`. I have used the following patterns with `preg_match()`, but they do not work.

```
'^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}^'  //  dd/mm/yyyy

'^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}^'  //  dd/mm/yy
```

Can someone help me to find the correct pattern?

Comment: This is an error caused by simple typographical errors that could have been identified by testing at www.regex101.com or doing a quick bit of research on regex syntax / reading SO pages.  This pattern and the accepted answer will at best do a loose validation of the date.  In other words, invalid dates like `99/99/9999` will be matched without a problem.  For best results use `checkdate()` or DateTime class functions to validate a date.

Comment: Notice how the best [answers on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format) do not use regex, and the ones that do only improve in quality as the pattern exponentially grows.  Using regex is not the best tool for checking dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems:**

> **1.** This `$` should be in end instead of `^`. `$` is for end of string.
>
> **2.**  Don't forget delimiters `/`.

**Regular expression:**

> `/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/` for strings like `10/10/1111`
>
> `/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}$/` for strings like `10/10/11`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/820509)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the syntax of your regular expression. In a regex, the start of the pattern is denoted by ^ while the end is by $.

You can use the following to validate the given date format.

```
$date_to_check = "22/06/2017";
$true = preg_match("/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/", $date_to_check);
var_dump($true);
```

However, you shouldn't be validating a date against a regex expression only. You need to pass the Year, month, date to the php's checkdate() function to really validate it.

[PHP checkdate() doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)