# How to check if the date is exist or not? (with all format)

Tags: php, date

I want to check a date exist or not with all format PHP like `d-m-Y` or `jS-F-`Y or `D-M-Y` ... ?

For example:

```
01-01-2018 => true
31-02-2018 => false
30 Februari 2018 => false
31st Feb 2018 => false
31st March 2018 => true
31-04-2018 => false
```

I found this function: [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) but it only can check date with number format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly determine if date string is a valid date in that format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format)

Comment: You need to validate against predefined set of formats. You cannot use some formats simultaneously, because you would lose precision - for example 5-6-12 could mean 3 valid dates: 2005-06-12, 05-06-2012, 06-05-2012 (as in May 6th, 2012).

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the examples overhere

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

```
<?php
var_dump(checkdate(12, 31, 2000));
var_dump(checkdate(2, 29, 2001));
?>
```

The above example will output:

bool(true)
bool(false)

```
var_dump(validateDate('Tue, 28 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', DateTime::RSS)); # true
var_dump(validateDate('Tue, 27 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', DateTime::RSS)); # false
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>