# Check that string is valid date

Tags: php, php-carbon

How can I check that my string is a valid date ("2018-01-01").

Is there a simple way, or do I need to do something like this:

```
if (Carbon::createFromFormat('YOUR DATE FORMAT', $stringVariable) !== false) {
    // valid date
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly determine if date string is a valid date in that format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format)

Comment: You should use DateTime class to check if this is valid date

Comment: Is your date always in that format? Or are you trying to use arbitrary user input?

Comment: I'm using a date picker so it should always be in that format.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp  = strtotime($date);

return $timestamp ? $date  : null ;
```

Comment: Although it works for the format "2018-01-01", it is worth remembering that for other date formats the result is false. for example, the date "13/10/2018" in the format "d/m/Y" is a valid date, but with strtotime, the result is false.

Comment: @MagnoAlberto The format d/m/Y is NOT a valid date format. If the separator is a slash (/), then the American `m/d/y` is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European `d-m-y` format is assumed.

Comment: be aware that a value of `$date = "first sat of July 2008";` would be considered a valid date https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php