# php - How to check "March 21, 2015" string is a valid date?

Tags: php, datetime-format, date-parsing

I am having a variable which holds date as string like March 21, 2015,so I need to check whether it is a valid in php.I tries to check using

`$date = 'July 20 2018';
 echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date))`;

But it showing error and also tried

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $myString) !== FALSE) { //valid date }
```

Getting error 2nd parameter must be string. Please anybody can help me !

Comment: So, `$myString` is not a string. Find a value which is __string__.

Comment: Also, in your call to `createFromFormat()`, `'Y-m-d G:i:s'` doesn't match to your format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly determine if date string is a valid date in that format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format)

Comment: If this answer is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

strtotime will parse the date string to a number:
please refer to [this.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_strtotime)

so the returned value from strtotime cannot be passed to createfromFromat as the second parameter.

You can use the following code to verify the date

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('July 25 2010', 'F j Y');
return $date && ($date->format('F j Y') === 'July 25 2010');
```