# How to validate a datetime in 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii P' format using jquery in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, validation, datetime, format

I have a datetime value and i need to check whether the entered datetime is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii P` ? How do i accomplish using jquery in PHP ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correctly determine if date string is a valid date in that format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [See better answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19271434/1427345)

I'm not sure what you mean by "using jquery in PHP", but you can determine if the datetime entered is a certain format doing something like the following:

```
<?php

$date = '13/04/2020 16:32 +02:00';
$format = 'd/m/Y H:i P';

function isValidDateFormat($date, $format)
{
    return $date === date($format, strtotime(str_replace('/','.', $date)));
}

var_dump($date);
var_dump(date($format, strtotime(str_replace('/','.', $date))));
var_dump(isValidDateFormat($date, $format));
```

The `str_replace` function is required because `strtotime` interprets any date with `/`s as using American m/d/Y format (a quite annoying "feature")

Output

```
string(23) "13/04/2020 16:32 +02:00"
string(23) "13/04/2020 16:32 +02:00"
bool(true)
```