# How to check given date is available in next month or not in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP so I have an issue with how to check given date is available next month or not

```
$startEventDate = "2021-03-31";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correctly determine if date string is a valid date in that format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format)

Comment: @AlexRobbio available in next month? in terms of?

Comment: Your question is unclear but if you have the date cant you check the month and using that information see if the date is in range? ie if you know the month is 04 then you can check that the day is between 1 and 30 inclusive

Comment: @AlexRobbio if next month is 04 then in this month (march) 31st date does exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the selected date falls between a start and end date, you can do something like: *(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7, PHP 8)*

```
    $startEventDate = new DateTime('2021-03-31');
    $start = new DateTime();
    $end = new DateTime();
    $end->modify('+1 month'); // 1 month from today


    if ($startEventDate > $start && $startEventDate <= $end) {
        $result = 'avaialble';
    } else {
        $result = 'not avaialble';
    }

    echo sprintf(
        'The selected date %s is %s between %s and %s',
        $startEventDate->format('Y-m-d'),
        $result,
        $start->format('Y-m-d'),
        $end->format('Y-m-d')
    );
```

More specific to your question:

> check given date is available in next month or not.

You can modify the code like

```
    $startEventDate = new DateTime('2021-03-31');
    $start = new DateTime('first day of next month');
    $end = new DateTime('last day of next month');
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question completely, but in my guess, you are looking for this

```
<?php  
//Get the next month and year like this
$startEventDate = date("2021-03-01");
$newDate = strtotime ( '+1 month' , strtotime ( $startEventDate ) ) ;


$nextMonthYear = date('Y', $newDate);
$nextMonth = date('m', $newDate);

$nextmonthdate = date($nextMonthYear."-".$nextMonth."-31"); // append your date to the next month and year
```

Now you can test if the `$nextmonthdate` is valid. There is a lot of ways to do that.

Comment: is it still working when you give date like this `$startEventDate = date("2021-03-31");`

Comment: When I echo this variable `$nextmonthdate` then output is `1970-01-31`

Comment: I have updated the code. Check with the updated code. Also, it is better to use the first day of the month when you want to find the next month and year of the current month.