# how can I check if a variable type is DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

How can I check if a variable is a datetime type on php, please?
I've tried this, but it seems doesn't work.

```
public function setRegistrationDate ($registrationDate) {

   if (!is_date($registrationDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) {
       trigger_error('registrationDate != DateTime', E_USER_WARNING);
       return;
   }

   $this->_registrationDate = $registrationDate;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

Reference:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332

Comment: 1 minutes to validate this, is it a good practice to regroup all of the business classes in aonly one file when we're OO php programming, please ?

Answer (score 61):

I think this way is more simple:

```
if (is_a($myVar, 'DateTime')) ...
```

This expression is true if `$myVar` is a PHP `DateTime` object.

Since PHP 5, this can be further simplified to:

```
if ($myVar instanceof DateTime) ...
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Since the other answers are old their approaches are outdated. This is the correct way to verify class type in PHP.  As a sidenote, single qutoes should be used as double quotes causes an extra step for variable interpolation that is not needed in these circumstances.

Comment: You are right. I just changed expression from double quotes to single quotes. Thanks Ryan.

Comment: I think the original question was how to determine whether a given string matches a particular format, rather than whether a particular PHP variable is an instance of a particular class.  As for single versus double quotes, the difference is negligible and worrying about such things is a micro-optimisation.  If your code is slow it's not slow because you used double-quotes. https://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html

Comment: The code in the question from OP is in fact trying to verify type on line 3.  As for micro optimization that isn't really the point.  It's about using the correct string enclosure.  It is negligible but its a matter of convention.  Not a matter of slowness but a matter of correct practice. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions

Comment: +1 Ryan. It makes sense to use the right enclosure, the only reason not to is laziness (though to be fair the PHP docs themselves generally use the wrong enclosures). Also, though it is a "micro" optimization, it's one that it multiplied countless times in a large codebase. It won't make or break anything but there is no logic in not doing it.

Comment: the best simple answer I have seen so far

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer is : **to check with [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function**

```
$date = strtotime($datevariable);
```

If it's valid date, it will return **timestamp**, otherwise returns **FALSE**.

Comment: Thanks for response, one more question please, is it a good practice to regroup all of the business classes in aonly one file when we're OO php programming, please ?

Comment: we should put one class in one file ideally.

Comment: No, I do not get false I get an error: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object give

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following method:

```
public function setRegistrationDate ($registrationDate) {
  if(!($registrationDate instanceof DateTime)) {
    $registrationDate = date_create_from_format("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss", $registrationDate)
  }

  if(!($registrationDate instanceof DateTime)) {
    trigger_error('registrationDate is not a valid date', E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
  }

  $this->_registrationDate = $registrationDate;
  return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, one more question please, is it a good practice to regroup all of the business classes in aonly one file when we're OO php programming, please ?

Comment: I usually tend to put one class in one file, following this convention (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) for better autoloading.