# Valid date or timestamp

Tags: php

How do you do the following in PHP?

Check to see a time passed into a function is a valid date or a timestamp (valid meaning after 1970 time)?

If neither, throw an error.

I was thinking

```
if(ctype_digit($time)) {
     if($time > time_in_1970) {
         // good
     } else {
         // bad
     }
} else {
   $date_from_time = strtotime($time);

   if($date_from_time === false) {
     // error
```

Comment: Can you make an example of an invalid value?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28 12:12:12')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-30 12:12:12')); # false
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28', 'Y-m-d')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('28/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('30/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # false
var_dump(validateDate('14:50', 'H:i')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14:77', 'H:i')); # false
var_dump(validateDate(14, 'H')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14', 'H')); # true
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Or you can use [checkdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function of php like below:

```
function IsDate( $Str )
{
  $Stamp = strtotime( $Str );
  $Month = date( 'm', $Stamp );
  $Day   = date( 'd', $Stamp );
  $Year  = date( 'Y', $Stamp );

  return checkdate( $Month, $Day, $Year );
}
```

Comment: That's good code to generally validate a date, but why use it? It's a timestamp. If it's a number, it can by definition never have an invalid value.

Comment: The first code block copied from http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php without attribution. Please don't do that, it's plagiarism and not allowed. Always provide a link to the original source. Thanks!

Comment: Not for the first code block. [PHP preg_match with working regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12322824)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the timestamp is greater than 0, it is a valid timestamp.

A timestamp of 0 = Dec 31, 1969

```
echo date("Y-m-d", 0);
```

This is because a UNIX timestamp is the measurement of seconds since the Epoch, AKA Dec 31, 1969

Comment: The Epoch is 1st of January, 1970 UTC.

Comment: Eh, I'm only off by one millisecond.  I was going by what I received at this sandbox
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dbd0161c4976782352e33c434f86043608f8ab32

Comment: Regardless, any timestamp greater than zero is valid.

Comment: I agree with that. What I don't agree with is calling Dec 31, 1969 the Epoch =P