# PHP validate date

Tags: php, date

im trying to validate a date in the YYYY-MM-DD in the $immerseusnorm i have tried the code below but its returning No!

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.wowtrack.org/plugins/guild/EU/Emerald%20Dream/VII?format=json", true);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$realmrank = " ". $decode[realmRank] ."";
$immerseusnorm = " ". $decode[encounters][0][completedOn]."";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$immerseusnorm))
{
$immerseusnorm = "Yes";
}
$immerseusnorm = "No";

echo "Realm Rank: $realmrank<br \>";
echo "Immerseus Normal - Completed On: $immerseusnorm<br \>"
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't some dashes be escaped in regexp like `\-`?

Comment: prepended space is not in the regex... can it be just that?

Comment: possible duplicate of **http://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should add else around the second $immerseusnorm, it now always sets it to no. So better change this:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$immerseusnorm))
{
$immerseusnorm = "Yes";
}
$immerseusnorm = "No";
```

to:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$immerseusnorm))
{
    $immerseusnorm = "Yes";
}else{
    $immerseusnorm = "No";
}
```

Comment: You might want to point out what the difference is and why it is different

Comment: You're right, I have added some introduction. Guessed it would be clear from the indentation.

Comment: for some reason after using `$immerseusnorm = " ". $decode[encounters][0][completedOn]."";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$immerseusnorm))
{
    $immerseusnorm = "Yes";
}else{
    $immerseusnorm = "No";
}` i am still getting no if i use it without the code i get `2013-09-11`

Answer (score 2):

I would attempt to create a DateTime object based on the format.  That way, you can validate both the format AND that the date it suggests is valid.  For example, a simple regex match with your pattern would allow something like `2014-02-31`, which obviously is not a valid date.

The only challenge with DateTime is that a date like `2014-02-31` gets "fixed" to `2014-03-03`, instead of returning false from `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. So you can just check back against the input string to make sure the date didn't get changed.

Putting it into a function could look like this:

```
function validate_date($input_date, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input_date);
    if(false === $datetime) {
        return false;
    } else if ($datetime->format($format) === $input_date) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


// usage
if (validate_date($immerseusnorm)) {
    // validation passed
} else {
    // validation failed
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend using identical comparison operator in the compare format part, because for an example, user can enter integer number like `validateDate(2014, 'Y')`; in this case `false` will be returned. **[And this function can be simplified to 2 lines, like this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332)**

Comment: @Glavić I would absolutely use an identical operator. In fact, if I was using this function in production I would force string input and I uld throw an Exception if the input was not a string input. Note that `createFromFormat()` method expects string as input for date. Yes, the function can be collapsed down, but there are no bonus points awards for the shortest possible code.  For demonstration purposes, I want to make sure the example is clearly understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your regex is working.
you have missed a point here.
 this line is always executed :

```
$immerseusnorm = "No";
```

You should have `else` of your `if` condition.

try this:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$immerseusnorm))
{
$immerseusnorm = "Yes";
}
else{
$immerseusnorm = "No";
}
```

Sample demo : see demo : https://eval.in/107333

Comment: still the same output im afraid

Comment: im baffled i think it may be something to do with json as if i enter my own date it responds yes