# validate invalid date character using php

Tags: php, validation

I have this php function for validation date format:

```
 function _CHECK_DATEFORMAT_($date, $format='YYYY/MM/DD')
   {
    switch( $format )
    {
        case 'YYYY/MM/DD':
        case 'YYYY-MM-DD':
        list( $y, $m, $d ) = preg_split( '/[-\.\/ ]/', $date );
        break;

        case 'YYYY/DD/MM':
        case 'YYYY-DD-MM':
        list( $y, $d, $m ) = preg_split( '/[-\.\/ ]/', $date );
        break;

        case 'DD-MM-YYYY':
        case 'DD/MM/YYYY':
        list( $d, $m, $y ) = preg_split( '/[-\.\/ ]/', $date ); //3715 LINE
        break;

        case 'MM-DD-YYYY':
        case 'MM/DD/YYYY':
        list( $m, $d, $y ) = preg_split( '/[-\.\/ ]/', $date );
        break;

        case 'YYYYMMDD':
        $y = substr( $date, 0, 4 );
        $m = substr( $date, 4, 2 );
        $d = substr( $date, 6, 2 );
        break;

        case 'YYYYDDMM':
        $y = substr( $date, 0, 4 );
        $d = substr( $date, 4, 2 );
        $m = substr( $date, 6, 2 );
        break;

        default:
        throw new Exception( "Invalid Date Format" );
    }
    return checkdate( $m, $d, $y ); //3738 Line
}
```

Code Output :

```
echo validateDate( '2007-21-04', 'YYYY-DD-MM' )  ? 'good'. "\n" : 'bad' . "\n";
```

This Worked but if user input invalid date character Like This :

```
echo validateDate( '2007*2104', 'YYYY-DD-MM' )  ? 'good'. "\n" : 'bad' . "\n";
echo validateDate( 'test', 'YYYY-DD-MM' )  ? 'good'. "\n" : 'bad' . "\n";
```

I see error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\functions.php on line 3715

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\functions.php on line 3715

Warning: checkdate() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\functions.php on line 3738
```

how do validate character before check for validate date format?

Comment: Where is your validateDate function?

Comment: `function _CHECK_DATEFORMAT_($date, $format) { return !!DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date); }` - Parsing dates is easier if you use the default functions, like createFromFormat, which parses the format and returns the datetime to you, or returns false. Either way `!!` converts it to boolean.

Comment: You should really limit the formats more, and only accept one way of writing dates. It will make everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

E better class for validating and formatting dates Without `DateTime` function :

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dateclass.html

Or

**You could use PHP's `DateTime` class:**

```
function validateDate($date)
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('Y/m/d') == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but that class was written before PHP had the more native DateTime class, why should we choose that class over the built in one which offers better support and faster access?

Comment: @scragar: I Share this for this Q(without PHP Native DateTime Class) . you right DateTime is better.

Answer (score 0):

`date` passed may obviously contain 1 or 2 slashes/minuses in, making `list` assignment inappropriate.

Warning is because [`checkdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) expects integer params.

```
return checkdate( intval($m), intval($d), intval($y) ); //3738 Line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use native php class [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for convert date string with special format to date

```
function _CHECK_DATEFORMAT_($date, $format='YYYY/MM/DD')
   {
    switch( $format )
    {
        case 'YYYY/MM/DD':
            $n_format="Y/m/d";
            break;
        case 'YYYY-MM-DD':
            $n_format="Y-m-d";
            break;
        case 'YYYY/DD/MM':
            $n_format="Y/d/m";
            break;
        case 'YYYY-DD-MM':
            $n_format="Y-d-m";
            break;
        case 'DD-MM-YYYY':
            $n_format="d-m-Y";
            break;
        case 'DD/MM/YYYY':
            $n_format="d/m/Y";
            break;
        case 'MM-DD-YYYY':
            $n_format="m-d-Y";
            break;
        case 'MM/DD/YYYY':
            $n_format="m/d/Y";
            break;
        case 'YYYYMMDD':
            $n_format="Ymd";
            break;
        case 'YYYYDDMM':
            $n_format="Ydm";
            break;
        default:
        throw new Exception( "Invalid Date Format" );
    }
    $date=DateTime::createFromFormat($n_format, $date);
    if(!$date){
        throw new Exception('Invalid Date by format '.$format);
    }
    $m=$date->format('m');
    $d=$date->format('d');
    $y=$date->format('Y');
    return checkdate( $m, $d, $y ); //3738 Line
}
```