# Validate Date format mm/dd/yyyy without any Regular Expression

Tags: php, date

I am trying to validate Date format `mm/dd/yyyy` with the below code:

**Date is 1st Feb, 2014

```
$is_valid_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('02/01/2014')) == 02/01/2014;
```

---

I've tried checking format `d-m-Y` in above code, it was working fine:

```
$is_valid_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('01-02-2014')) == 01-02-2014;
if( ! $is_valid_date){
    echo 'invalid date';
}
```

How to do 1 scenario without using any **regular expression** ??

Comment: With dash `-` strtotime assumes date is `dd-mm-yyyy`.  With slash `/` it assumes `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: You can use this function > http://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make date into string by quotation

```
<?php
$is_valid_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('01-02-2014')) == "01/02/2014";

if(  $is_valid_date){
    echo 'Valid date';
} 
else if ( !$is_valid_date)
{
    echo 'invalid date';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could explode by "/" and then validate the date with the function [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php).

```
$date = '02/01/2014';
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("/", $date);
$is_valid_date = checkdate($month, $day, $year);

var_dump($is_valid_date);
```

Comment: what if the date format is `02-01-2014`?? Than `explode` will not work... right??

Comment: @user3030089 No. My code assumes that you know what separator is being used.