# RegExp not working the way it should

Tags: php, regex, date

I am trying to get a RegExp that accepts dates in the following formats:

dd/mm/yyyy
dd/m/yyyy
d/mm/yyyy
d/m/yyyy

I am using this as my parseDate() /* which is supposed to return true if the date is in the right format */

```
function parseDate(&$date)
    {
        global $incorrectDateFormat;
        // trim $date
        $date = trim($date);
        // if date is not in mm/yy/dddd format
        if (!preg_match('/(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/', $date))
        {
            // the format is invalid
            echo $incorrectDateFormat;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The first argument in preg_match is the RegExp, and if I am not mistaken, ? after criteria means 0 or 1 occurrence of criteria. What is wrong with my RegExp? (It is returning true for these obviously incorrect dates:
"102/25/2014
 101/25/2014"

Comment: You need to use start and end anchors. `if (!preg_match('/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$/', $date))`

Comment: But validating dates with regex wouldn't be a recommended way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_match with working regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332)