# Import CSV file with a column having date or text inside

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file with a column having a date in format d/m/Y or the word "Illimité" inside meaning unlimited in French.

I would like each time it reads "Illimité" it puts NULL value inside MySQL table.

Here is my current PHP code :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `formation` ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {

            $nom = $fileop[0];
            $prenom = $fileop[1];
            $formation = $fileop[16];
            $validite = $fileop[26];

            if (is_numeric($validite)) {
                $validite = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $validite), 'Y-m-d');
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO formation (nom,prenom,formation,validite,usermaj) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$formation','$validite','importCSV')");
                } else {
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO formation (nom,prenom,formation,validite,usermaj) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$formation',NULL,'importCSV')");
            }
        }
```

Sadly this isn't working. MySql shows no errors and it puts NULL all the time.
Any help would me much appreciate.

Comment: Make your DB as Charaset -UTF-8 encoded

Comment: so your if statement is not passing, have you tried to var_dump($validite), does it give numeric value so it would have a chance to pass?

Comment: @SunilPachlangia I cannot change it to UTF-8 because the type = date in MySQL

Comment: A date is not numeric so it always go's to the else statement

Comment: @JelledeFries and SunilPachlangia You are both right it's not numeric ! My mistake. I need to find how to test if it's a date in format d/m/Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunc($CSVValue){

    if(validateDate($CSVValue)){
        //your mysql logic where you put in the date
    }else{
        //your mysql logic where you put in the null
    }


}

function validateDate($date)
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('d/m/Y') == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

-- update --

I don't know how your code looks other than what you have provided.
If you were to put this in your code it could look something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `formation` ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {

            $nom = $fileop[0];
            $prenom = $fileop[1];
            $formation = $fileop[16];
            $validite = $fileop[26];

            $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $validite);

            if ($d && $d->format('d/m/Y') == $validite) {
                $validite = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $validite), 'Y-m-d');
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO formation (nom,prenom,formation,validite,usermaj) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$formation','$validite','importCSV')");
                } else {
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO formation (nom,prenom,formation,validite,usermaj) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$formation',NULL,'importCSV')");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying your code and it's not working. I'm getting Fatal error: Cannot redeclare myFunc()

Comment: You should put in some effort yourself, my code is just a template. you shouldn't just copy it.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It's working perfectly ! I didn't understood how your code was working what i did was wrong. I still have much to learn. Good day !