# How do I check the date format in html input tag

Tags: php, html, validation, input

Here is my input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="EndDate" value="<?php echo $StartDate; ?>">
```

I am using PHP as well so I have made a function to do this task:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
     $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
     return $d && $d->format($format) == $date)
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

My question is how do I incorporate the function into the input tag? Or if there is an easier way please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case where a ternary statement would be helpful:

```
<?php $StartDate = validateDate($StartDate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s') ? $StartDate : ''; ?>
```

This uses the true/false return value of `validateDate($StartDate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')` then assigns `$StartDate` on true or assigns an empty string `''` on false. In short, it keeps valid dates and blanks out invalid dates.