# PHP: Create custom filter_var() constants

Tags: php, constants, filter-var

How would i go about creating custom filters for use in PHP `filter_var()`.

An example:

Right now i have a function to validate a date:

```
    private function validateDate($date){
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
        return $d && $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date;
    }
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

I want to be able to call a constant like `FILTER_VALIDATE_DATE` and have it checked by the above code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't. But you can pass in a callback / closure. Why don't you just make your own function like `filter_date()`?

Answer (score 4):

PHP does not have a way for you to register a custom filter, so you can't simply make a new constant to pass in. The best thing you can do is use the `FILTER_CALLBACK` and pass the callback in as the third argument, like so:

```
$valid = filter_var($date, FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => 'validateDate']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use filter callback functions.

```
$date = "2015-06-30";

echo filter_input( $date, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => 'validateDate') );
```