# Check if I'm passing only a date without time

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way on PHP I can check if I'm posting only a date without a time?

```
Ex. 
2015-11-18            ->   TRUE
2015-11-18 00:00:00   ->   FALSE
2015-11-18 23:59:00   ->   FALSE
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use regex to validate. or  `preg_match`

Comment: string length should surfice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current date you can use-

```
date("Y-m-d")
```

It gives only the date.

or if you already have a date -

```
$date = '10.21.2011';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('.', '/', $date)));
```

to validate you can use `preg_match`-

```
$date="10.21.2011";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date))
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

$date = "2014-04-01 12:00:00";

preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/',$date);
```

[function.checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

Comment: This is wrong. He want's to validate not to get the date only.

Comment: Yes he can. He want's to only validate the date given.

Comment: I used preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/", $datetime) ). It worked pretty well. Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [my function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) <sup>[(or on PHP.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)</sup> to validate date&time for this purpose:

```php
var_dump( validateDate('2015-11-18', 'Y-m-d') );           # true
var_dump( validateDate('2015-11-18 00:00:00', 'Y-m-d') );  # false
var_dump( validateDate('2015-11-18 23:59:00', 'Y-m-d') );  # false
```

**<kbd>[demo](https://eval.in/470903)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a simple way .
What I have done is , I split the string into an array .
As all the 3 strings (Date sample given by you),differentiates from each other by `:`  symbol. So Split it and use `count()` method.if its split then `count()` will return `value > 1` .That's it in a simple way..

```
<?php 

//U can use $a=date("Y-m-d");

$a='2015-11-18'; //Here i am taking an Example 
$b=explode(':' , $a);
if(count($b)>1)
{
   echo "FALSE";
}else
{
echo "TRUE";
}
```

Hope You were expecting something like this .

> Note- I have answered as per your question.For general case it will be
>   different.

Comment: You can shorten your example to `strpos('2015-11-18', ':') === false`, see [example](https://eval.in/471324).