# php/mysql: strToTime error manipulating dates

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

I have some code for rendering dates that was working great for a couple of years and is now broken.  I don't know if it has something to do with my host changing version of PHP or somehow an error crept in.

Basically, dates such as `11/30/15` are now getting rendered as `11/30/-1`

Here is an example of what is going on:

```
$olddate = $row['date'];//in database this looks like:0000-00-00 00:00:00
$newdate = nicedate($olddate);
echo "starting date time: ".$olddate;//displays as 'starting date time: 0000-00-00 00:00:00'
echo "after transforming it with nice date: ".$newdate; //displays as 'after transforming it with nice date: 11/30/-1'
```

I also tried just running strtotime and get this:

```
echo "after transforming it with strtotime: ".nicedate($row['starttime']);//-62169966000

    // gets nice data
    function nicedate($datetime) {
    $niceDate = strtotime($datetime);
    $niceDate = date("m/d/y",$niceDate);
    return $niceDate;
    }
```

Comment: echo out the $olddate to see if it is printed right. If it does than it has something to do with the version you are running. Also recommend using mysqli or PDO if you are not already doing.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here https://3v4l.org/8gqCK it really depends on which PHP version you are using.

PHP will render the string `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to `-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000`

**This is an example output from [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

The OUTPUT also depends on the time zone:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "-0001-11-29 23:06:32.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

This would output:

> ...with nice date: 11/29/-1

**And here [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):**

```
int(-62169987208)
```

So you see the date function were changed on different version, what you can do now ist just to check if the date is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`:

```
function nicedate ( $datetime ) {
    if( $datetime == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ) return "Some value or false?";
    ...
    ...
}
```

You also have a look at the **MySQL** mode: [`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date)

**Updated approach due to the comments below:**

```
function nicedate( $datetime ) {
    if( !validateDate( $datetime ) ) return "something";
    $dateTimeObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime );
    return $dateTimeObject->format( "m/d/y" );
}

function validateDate($date) {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

This is because `0000-00-00....` is not a valid date. What happens is simple, from year, month, day,... is alway one (1) substracted from the last.

```
0000 -1 = -1// year
00 - 1 = 11// month, because 12 is the highest value that datetime recognizes as month
00 - 1 = 30// day, because 31 is the highest value that datetime recognizes as day
```

For hours, minutes, seconds,.. it's ok, because zero is a valid value for time.

That's why it is rendered like this: `-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000`

Comment: Can you recommend way to bullet proof the code to PHP versions so it always returns a normal date? Not clear if the only time there is an issue is if the date time is 000-00 ... and you just need to check for that as in your function above or if this error can crop up in other cases. I would like to put something in a function

Comment: Bulletproof is nothing ;), but you can try the function in my updated answer

Comment: This produced same result with year as -1.  I think you have diagnosed problem.  Question is how to make year display properly.  Month and day are okay  In other words, if you test for 00s, what how could I get it to display correctly with what must be PHP 5.3 or so.

Comment: I think I can't follow you: maybe you can show me here https://3v4l.org/EJvfQ what problem you have and with which datetime string

Comment: How would you manipulate 0000-00-00 00:00:00 so that it shows up correctly as today's date i.e. 11/30/15, NOT 11/30/-1

Comment: you can put this: `if( $datetime == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ) {$datetime = "2015-11-30 00:00:00";}` in the function nicedate() on top of the first return, but think about it: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` **is NOT a valid date* so you should handle this and not manipulate this date

Comment: I hear you.  There are a lot these dates in the dbase as it seems to have been a default base in mysql if not null