# validate date with milliseconds

Tags: php, validation, time

I am having a problem when validating a time that brings milliseconds. I'm loading records in my database with data coming from an excel. I want to validate the time.

```
if(!($this->validateDate($array_to_validate['control_tiempo_oficial'], 'H:i:s')) || empty($array_to_validate['control_tiempo_oficial'])){
        $custom_errors['control_tiempo_oficial'] = 'El formato ingresado no es correcto.';
        $error = true;
}
```

As you can see valid only have hours, minutes and seconds. When the data is validated it is `00:00:00,00` (contains ,). Spend validations (and what I find strange). But when `00:00:00.00` fails. I need to do is that both pass validation if they come with that data.

Use this function to validate dates and times also in these cases, but I could not get that with this format works milliseconds.

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Comment: Datetime doesn't support microseconds, unless they changed it without me knowing about it..

Comment: `$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u'` perhaps