# Zend framework 2 validate date

Tags: php, validation, date, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How do I validate if the date is valid in this format? `Y-m`

For an instance, date is `2016-00`, this should return as invalid as there is no such month of `00`.

`2016-01` should return as valid since `01` represents as January.

I tried using `Date::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2016-00')` but it returns this:

```
object(DateTime)[682]
  public 'date' => string '2015-12-25 06:07:43' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Antarctica/Casey' (length=16)
```

in which it considers it as a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround but I suppose it works. You can use this function:

```
function validateDate($date, $format)
{
    $dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);// create a DateTime object of the given $date in the given $format
    return $dateTime && $dateTime->format($format) === $date;// returns true when the conversion to DateTime succeeds and formatting the object to the input format results in the same date as the input
}

var_dump(validateDate('2016-00', 'Y-m'));// returns false
var_dump(validateDate('2016-01', 'Y-m'));// returns true
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

In your case it would return false as `$dateTime->format($format) == $date` would return false.

Hope this helps.