# PHP preg_match combined with checkdat

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this piece of code in the middle of my web application.

```
  if (preg_match ("/^[-0-9]/", $strDate) == TRUE)
  {
      $dateParts = explode("-", $strDate);
      if (count($dateParts) === 3)
      {
          try
          {
              if (checkdate($dateParts[0], $dateParts[1], $dateParts[2]) === TRUE)
              {
                  return TRUE;
              }
          }
          catch (Exception $e)
          {
              //purposely blank for now.
          }
      }
  }
```

I haven't included any surrounding code because it's a fairly lengthy app. To start, the `$strDate` variable I know exactly what is held in there. I can echo it out right before the `if` statement begins. If `$strDate` is a valid date or any combination of 'TBD' the statement validates as expected. The problem comes when an invalid date enters the function.

For instance,

```
$strDate = '03-01-2017asdf';
```

With this input I would expect the `preg_match` to catch it and kick it out of the `if` statement. Instead it runs the try-except and php throws a non formed number error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? I'm sure it has to do with my `preg_match` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your regular expression to require a match until the end of the input string:

```
/^[-0-9]+$/
```

So add the `+` to say you can have multiple digits and hyphens, and then the `$` to say that the previous pattern must match until the end of the string, so nothing else can be added like in your example. Of course, you could look for more complex regular expressions that check for valid parts of the date, the number of hyphens, ... etc, which can become quite complex, as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877/5459839).

Comment: Glad that you added `$` sign, but the date pattern still could be better.

Comment: Yea, folding the date match into the pattern was the next step. I just wanted to get this part working first. This totally worked! Thanks! I knew it was a little tiny error like that and just couldn't figure it out. After searching on here and around the web for hours I gave up and actually asked a question.

Comment: It would be easier to ready if you use paragraphs ;-) But UP from me anyway

Comment: While I agree text has to be broken down into paragraphs, I don't think every sentence has to be a separate paragraph either :P

Answer (score 0):

Your `preg_match` checks whether the `$strDate` begins with a digit - not whether the date format altogether is correct... Since `03-01-2017asdf` begins with a digit, the condition results as `TRUE`.

For the given date format (`MM-DD-YYYY`), you may use this code:

```
if (preg_match ("/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-[0-9]{4}$/", $strDate) == TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to validate and format your dates to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)

here an example of code to do what you do in your function:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
class DateHelper
{
    /**
     * @param $strDate valid format d-m-Y
     */
    public static function validate($strDate)
    {
        try {
            $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $strDate);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception) {
            //invalid date
        }

        return false;
    }

}

var_dump(DateHelper::validate('03-01-2017asdf'));  //return false
var_dump(DateHelper::validate('03-01-2017'));  //return true
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant and shortest way to validate your dates would be to use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) php object.

You could build your function like this :

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

i.e. :

```
var_dump(validateDate('03-01-2017asdf', 'm-d-Y')); // bool(false)
var_dump(validateDate('03-01-2017', 'm-d-Y')); // bool(true)
```

So your validation condition will look like this :

```
if (validateDate($strDate, 'm-d-Y')) {
    ...
    // Do some stuff
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.