# php check if DateTime parsing is possible

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a possibility to check if `DateTime()` can parse a string? When I try for example:

```
new DateTime('05.06.17');
```

DateTime cant parse it and will throw a Exception. So, how can I prevent this and check before if the parsing is possible? There is a lot of possible formats DateTime can read and I don't want to check each of them with regex...

Comment: I think `date_parse` is what you need. It will return `false` on an invalid date

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) which will take a date string and return an array containing details of the date. If it can't be parsed then it will return `false` so you can use:

```
if (date_parse($myDateSring) !== false) {
    //valid date
}
```

If `$myDateSring` is a valid date the function will return an indexed array of the date parts. For example:

```
print_r(date_parse("2006-12-12 10:00:00.5"));

Array
    (
        [year] => 2006
        [month] => 12
        [day] => 12
        [hour] => 10
        [minute] => 0
        [second] => 0
        [fraction] => 0.5
        [warning_count] => 0
        [warnings] => Array()
        [error_count] => 0
        [errors] => Array()
        [is_localtime] => 
    )
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work: `var_dump(date_parse('16/03/2017 17:13'))` gives true but `new DateTime('16/03/2017 17:13')` does not work

Comment: In that case you may need to inspect the resulting array and extract the parts you are interested in. I will update my answer with the example from the docs

Answer (score 0):

The best option in this case is to make function which check if date is correct taking into account format.

If date can be created the it can be parse.

```
function validateDate($date, $format) {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Function return `true` or `false`.

Comment: OK I see your point. My Question is why you don't like Exception in case of an error?