# PHP: How can I include this function in a class?

Tags: php, function, class

I'm wondering how I can include this DateTime function inside a class?

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

It works outside, but not inside the class.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Certainly you can implement any function you want as a method of a class. So the answer to your question simply is: _you just have to do that._

Comment: What do you mean by "It works outside, but not inside the class."? A function / method that "does not work"? How that?

Comment: Are you including the file that contains this function anywhere with the class?

Comment: If your class belongs to a namespace you have to also put `use DateTime` under the namespace declaration.

Comment: It is impossible to answer to a question like this without additional information. It is not at all clear what your actual issue is. You will have to add more information to your question.

Comment: In what way ___does it not work in a class___ Show us how you codes it in the class!

Comment: _Why does this code not work when I do it some other way_ is really not helping us help you. Please show us how you code this in a class otherwise you are not going to get any answers of any use to you

Answer (score 1):

To add the function to the class you'd simply do something like:

```
class myClass {
   public function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
      $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
      return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
   }
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

I've added a \ infront of DateTime just in-case you are namespacing things but you might not need it.

You could then use the function by doing something like:

```
$myObj = new myClass();
echo $myObj->validateDate($date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class myDate {
    // your function
}

$instance = new myDate();
$instance->yourFuncion(yourParameters);
```