# A four digit year could not be found Data missing in Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date

```
InvalidArgumentException: A four digit year could not be found
Data missing in carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php:425
```

Getting this error in my apache logs. What is the cause of this type of error?

Comment: `Carbon.php:425` is clearly mentioned in log. check that file 425 line number (check 2-3 line above that line too). Issue will be there

Answer (score 2):

Running this on the date first should fix it. Likely getting an invalid date from the front-end.

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I faced and fixed that problem and problem was that I was using the guard method in the eloquent model and then I was trying to save data using create method. Problem was that the array I was providing to create method as a parameter has an extra column apart from the table's column so somehow our created_at or updated_at field was getting disturbed.
Once I fixed the extra column issue. The error was removed.

Comment: how did you fix the extra column issue

Comment: I just removed the extra column