# Date not properly formatted into a string

Tags: php, jquery

In this code I am converting date format `dd-mm-yy` to `yy-mm-dd`. When I echo `$from` date it gives the correct date (`2017-6-1`).  Similarly with `echo $to`. 
 But when I echo the query it can't get value of `$from`, but `$to` it gets the date correctly.  What is the problem with `$from`?

Here is my code...

```
<script language='javascript'>
    jQuery(function($)
           { 
               $("#from").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
               $("#to").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
           });
</script>

<input name="from" id="from" type="text" />
<input name="to" id="to" type="text" />

<?php
    $froms = $_POST['from'];
    list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-", $froms);
    $from = "$year-$month-$day";

    $too = $_POST['to'];
    list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-", $too);
    $to = "$year-$month-$day";

    if($from = "$year-$month-$day" && $to = "$year-$month-$day")
    {
        echo "select * from students where (enquiry_date between '$from' and '$to')";
    }
?>
```

Result:

```
select * from students where (enquiry_date between '1' and '2017-06-09') order by student_id
```

Comment: `if($from = "$year-$month-$day" && $to = "$year-$month-$day")` Quite sure you wanted to use `==` instead of `=` Also you should think about your IF statement again. IMO it doesn't make any sense, even with double `==`

Comment: I am trying this @Twinfriends but query does't echo.

Comment: It doesn't display because your if statement doesn't make any sense. I don't think its "true" - so it simply skips that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to use '==' instead of '=' when you are comparing.

Otherwise, I think you are trying to check if the date format is entered correctly.

If so, replace line:

```
if($from = "$year-$month-$day" && $to = "$year-$month-$day")
```

with this line:

```
if(validateDate($from) && validateDate($to))
```

and make sure you define the function validateDate:

```
function validateDate($date)
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

User PHP Date funtion for date formating:

```
<?php
    $froms = $_POST['from'];
    $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($froms));

    $too = $_POST['to'];
    $to  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($too ));

    echo "select * from students where (enquiry_date between '".$from."' and '".$to."')";
?>
```