# PHP DateTime CreateFromFormat Issue

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'm-Y') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}


validateDate('09-2017', 'm-Y');
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

I'm very puzzled to why this returns false while it returns true for the previous months. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're not supplying a day, so it's using the current day by default. Current day is 31, but September only has 30 days, so it skips to October 1st.

Look at this example:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'm-Y') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    echo $d->format("d-".$format); // added the day for debugging
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
var_dump(validateDate('08-2017', 'm-Y')); // 31-08-2017, true
var_dump(validateDate('09-2017', 'm-Y')); // 01-10-2017, there's no 31-09-2017, false
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

This is a little rudimentary, but you can detect if there's no `d` in the format and manually set it to 1 to avoid this:

```
<?php
function validateDate($date, $format = 'm-Y') {
    if (strpos($format, "d") === false) {
        $format = "d ".$format;
        $date = "01 ".$date;
    }
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
var_dump(validateDate('08-2017', 'm-Y')); // 31-08-2017, true
var_dump(validateDate('09-2017', 'm-Y')); // 01-09-2017, true
```

Comment: Ahhhhh! Nice catch! Excellent explanation. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: It's no problem! I added a possible solution I didn't like at all, but check it out!

Comment: Beautiful! I love the quick lookup for "d" within the format. Seems like the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not supplying a day. current one is used; just like explained in previous answer.
But this can be quickly solved with one format sign: `!`, which resets all fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction and timezone information) to the Unix Epoch; see [format table](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Fix:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'm-Y') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('!'.$format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Comment: How was my function copied? It’s two lines of code to do a typical date check, and not even complicated lines. I even made a mistake lol. Great answer though, didn’t know about `!`, +1 Thanks.