# Regex pattern for date (ex. August 9, 2011)

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex and I'm having problem understanding how to formulate a pattern to a date for example (August 9, 2011)

Comment: Don't use a regex, use php's `strtotime` or `DateTime`.

Comment: @BjörnTantau Used DateTime and it worked pretty well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not best suited for date validation. Use PHP's built-in function to do so.

You can do it this way:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Use it this way:

```
var_dump(validateDate('August 9, 2011', 'F j, Y')); # true
```

You can pass various date format as follows:

```
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28', 'Y-m-d')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('28/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('30/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # false
var_dump(validateDate('14:50', 'H:i')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14:77', 'H:i')); # false
```

Comment: thanks! tried using the DateTime format and it worked well.