# How to check if 2 different format date strings is a valid dates?

Tags: php, date

I need to check if 2 different format date strings is a valid dates. The formats are: `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY.MM.DD`. I found just only one date string format validation, like so:

```
function validateDate($date)
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

But how about two date formats validation? How to solve it? Thanks for any help

Comment: You pass the format as a parameter and run the function twice?

Comment: same as you solved first one

Answer (score 1):

Try the following for both:

```
$date="2017-09-11";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date)) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}

$date="2017.10.22";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}.(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date)) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
```

It uses regex to check if the format is valid or not.

OR

```
$date="2017-09-11";
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);
echo  $dt !== false && !array_sum($dt->getLastErrors());


$date="2017.10.22";

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y.m.d", $date);
echo  $dt !== false && !array_sum($dt->getLastErrors());
```

It uses `DateTime` to check the date against both formats.

**Edit:** While both are decent solutions, [benchmarks](https://3v4l.org/H8C73) show that in this case, `preg_match` is considerably faster than `DateTime`. https://3v4l.org/H8C73

Comment: Why do you want to use regex instead of the `DateTime()` methods?

Comment: @Manav Thanks for the comment. I have added `DateTime` method too.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the [original function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332), where you specify format as 2nd parameter, and then run function twice; as already mentioned in the comments.

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

$isValid = validDate($date, 'Y-m-d') || validDate($date, 'Y.m.d');
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>